# Used Hard drives for RAID?

Tags: hard-drive, raid, nas

I was requested to setup a RAID system(I chose either RAID 5 or 6).

Only problem is that my employer does not want the RAID system right away and would like to use 2 of the hard drives as external storage for a few months.

Does a RAID system support the usage of hard drives that are not clear of data at initialization and if so, what would the implications/problems be?

Comment: It does not matter, the initialization of the RAID will be the same regardless if the HDD has data on it.

Comment: Relatedly - dont use RAID5 if using hdd. It is generally considered unreliable for 2tb or larger disks due to risk of second failure during rebuild. Even if you start with smaller hdd's cgances are they will be swapped out.

Answer (score 2):

Typically when setting up any RAID it wipes the contents of the drive as part of the initialization process.
RAID is coming more uncommon in favor of other solutions.

Comment: RAID is coming more uncommon ... What?

Comment: @sickest disagre about RAID becoming less common - it is often done differently, or done on the computers of other people (aka cloud) on which the data lands up.

Comment: @davidgo. I'm questioning his wording on his answer. I think what he's trying to say is, RAID is BECOMING more uncommon in favor of other solutions. His poor English was the point of my comment.

Comment: Yes sorry my English is terrible :/